# Collapsed faces on subsurface

Tags: modeling, faces

On subsurface I'm getting unexpected result like on

[image]

but I would like to receive result with smooth surface (not collapsed faces)

What could be wrong in my model ?

Comment: do they meet at one point

Comment: This happens around non-quads (faces that don't have exactly 4 vertices). The solution is to add supporting geometry so that the curved surface is surrounded with quads and the tris/ngons are on flat surfaces surrounded by more quads.

Comment: @Chebhou yes, they meet at one point. I will check it later, thx for support,

Comment: @gandalf3 ok, I will try to fix it, thx

Comment: @gandalf3 Chebhou (I can only ping one of you :O) do either of you want to answer this so we can take it off *the list*?